# AppScript creates doc, but not replacing body text

Tags: google-apps-script, debugging

I created a script to create a new Google Doc once someone completes our Google Form. The doc creates as expected, but the body text is not replaced. Can someone help?

I tried changing the name tags in the template file thinking maybe there were unexpected spaces or format issues, but nothing helped. I'm not a developer, so I'm having issues debugging this.

The only error I'm receiving says "Exception: Invalid argument: id"

Here is portion of the script pertinent to the replacetext:

```
function AutoFillVTQFromForm(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Name = e.values[1];
  var Company = e.values[2];
  var TraditionalModern = e.values[3];
  var TMExplanation = e.values[4];
  var BoldConfident = e.values[5];
  var BCExplanation = e.values[6];
  var RationalEmotional = e.values[7];
  var REExplanation = e.values[8];
  var ExclusiveInclusive = e.values[9];
  var EIExplanation = e.values[10];
  var SeriousPlayful = e.values[11];
  var SPExplanation = e.values[12];
  var ConversationalCorporate = e.values[13];
  var CCExplanation = e.values[14];
  var SophisticatedSimple = e.values[15];
  var SSExplanation = e.values[16];
  var BrandVoiceNo = e.values[17];
  var BrandVoiceYes = e.values[18];
  var Competitors = e.values[19];
  var TemplateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1mJNG41sjaJV5Mwh3dDNSMPxY9LOmq8RfKDj7gL4Vnlc");
  var TemplateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Wxlkexc8RZ1EVBkUQLujlqZGtOaRNaDX");
  var copy = TemplateFile.makeCopy(Company + " - " + Name + " - " + Timestamp, TemplateResponseFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getID());
  var body = doc.getbody();
  body.replacetext("{{Timestamp}}", Timestamp)
  body.replacetext("{{Name}}", Name);
  body.replacetext("{{Company}}", Company);
  body.replacetext("{{TraditionalModern}}", TraditionalModern);
  body.replacetext("{{TMExplanation}}", TMExplanation);
  body.replacetext("{{BoldConfident}}", BoldConfident);
  body.replacetext("{{BCExplanation}}", BCExplanation);
  body.replacetext("{{RationalEmotional}}", RationalEmotional);
  body.replacetext("{{REExplanation}}", REExplanation);
  body.replacetext("{{ExclusiveInclusive}}", ExclusiveInclusive);
  body.replacetext("{{EIExplanation}}", EIExplanation);
  body.replacetext("{{SeriousPlayful}}", SeriousPlayful);
  body.replacetext("{{SPExplanation}}", SPExplanation);
  body.replacetext("{{ConversationalCorporate}}", ConversationalCorporate);
  body.replacetext("{{CCExplanation}}", CCExplanation);
  body.replacetext("{{SophisticatedSimple}}", SophisticatedSimple);
  body.replacetext("{{SSExplanation}}", SSExplanation);
  body.replacetext("{{BVDontLike}}", BrandVoiceNo);
  body.replacetext("{{BVDoLike}}", BrandVoiceYes);
  body.replacetext("{{Competitors}}", Competitors);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `copy.getID()` should be this: `copy.getId()`

This: `doc.getbody()` should be this: `doc.getBody()`

This: `body.replacetext(` should be this: `body.replaceText(`

Comment: Thanks. I did this and the error I'm seeing says:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
AutoFillVTQFromForm @ Code.gs:3

I assume this means my values are wrong?

Comment: Still nothing. I ran the debug option and I'm getting "undefined" for "e" as well as all of my variables. I'm missing an obvious step here.

Comment: You cannot run this function without the onFormSubmit event object which comes from the trigger.  e is undefined without the the trigger.  Try testing  with a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but ChatGPT for the win. Fixed my error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).